# How to calculate lift force of a revolved NACA 0009 airfoil?

Tags: aerodynamics

How would I calculate the lift force as a function of angle of attack for a revolved NACA 0009 3D body (incompressible flow)? I have data for CL vs. AoA for the 2D airfoil, but how would I use this to calculate the lift force on the body?

In the lift equation, I'm specifically wondering what to use for CL and S. (dynamic pressure is straightforward)

Would I just use planform area of the 3D body for S and 3D, incompressible lift coefficient for CL? Where AR is the aspect ratio of the body. See below for 3D adjusted equations.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like an airship  maybe [this](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19930091467) report NACA can help you. Anyway do not expect it to generate lot of lift: I would say an order of magnitude less than the relevant airfoil. And for sure you cannot use the equation you posted which is for wings i.e. something with a span much higher than the chord and the thickness.

Comment: Thank you sophit. This paper is excellent

Comment: You're welcome 

Answer (score 3):

This 3D shape will not generate appreciable lift.  It will not behave like an airfoil.